How to change "References" to "Bibliography" when using document class {article} without using .bib file?
My document is like this:
\documentclass{article}
 \title{Some Title}
 \author{}
  \date{}
 \begin{document}
\maketitle
 \begin{thebibliography}{00}
\bibitem{1a}{Some cited reference 1}
\bibitem{1a}{Some cited reference 2}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}

It gives me References as title of Bibliography but not Bibliography as title. I am not using .bib file but I am embedding the references in the document itself.
There is a question here but it does not solve my problem.
Please help.

Add to your preamble:
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}


thanks, that solve my problem. Is there a way by which bibliography can come as a Section of Latex document when class is article.

@Userhanu it is a section in article class by default.
